# Docker from a container calls to another container (Connection Refused)

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have container for two NodeJS services and one Nginx for reverse-proxy.

I have make NGINX on port 80 so it's publicly available via localhost on my browser

I also use reverse-proxy to proxy_pass to each responsible service.

```
  location /api/v1/service1/ {
    proxy_pass http://service1:3000/;
  }

  location /api/v1/service2/ {
    proxy_pass http://service2:3000/;
  }
```

In my service 1, there is an axios module that wants to call to service 2 by making a request to `localhost/api/v1/service2`

But, it says that connection is refused. I doubt if the `localhost` in service 1 refer to its container, not the docker host.

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: './service1'
    networks:
      - backend
  service2:
    build: './service2'
    networks:
      - backend
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Even after using network, it still says ECONNREFUSED.
Please help.

Comment: As you note, `localhost` for the server1 container is the server1 container.  You probably need to make that host name configurable.

Comment: @DavidMaze any idea how? So, should I just use http://servicename ? I'm trying to connect to localhost, so when I change my API service, it changes automatically without renaming all http://servicename to http://servicename_new

Comment: You are _not_ trying to connect to `localhost` ("this container"), you are trying to connect to a service running somewhere else.  If you have a hard-coded host name in your source code you need to make that configurable, most likely by getting its value from an environment variable.

Comment: @DavidMaze you'd better post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `depends_on` in your docker-compose file for the `nginx`, like below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: './service1'
    expose:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - backend
  service2:
    build: './service2'
    expose:
      - "3000"
    networks:
      - backend
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - service1
      - service2

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

This would make sure that both services are running first before the nginx container attempts to connect to them. Perhaps the connection is refused because the nginx container keeps crashing due to it not finding the two services running when it executes its conf file and connect to the backends.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Anyway, tha's not my question. Both services have started. What I want to do is: How does one container refer to the main host (by connecting to localhost in the main host, not the container) ?